# Chart.js multiple dataset issue: hovering over n-th point "hovers" over every dataset's n-th point

Tags: chart.js

**Example situation: I have 2 line datasets in one chart.**

if I hover over the second dataset's second point, it also detects hover at every other dataset's second point.

[image]

Comment: consider making a fiddle that reproduces the issue.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/qjLm6znm/3/
Here it is. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set chart­*'s* hover mode to ['**nearest**'](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#nearest), in your chart options config, like so :

```
options: {
      hover: {
         mode: 'nearest'
      },
      ...
```

this will ensure that only the hovered data-point gets active.

Here is the [**working fiddle**](https://fiddle.jshell.net/d47wpx8m/).